Why was my post about recovering save data closed?
I asked the following question, which was closed "requiring details or clarity".
How do I recover save progress on my games after resetting my iPad?
What details do I need to add? Please help me here.

Disregard all of that. The close reason used completely threw me off, and blinded me to the fact this question really is better asked over on Ask Different, our Apple dedicated sister site. I've gone ahead and migrated your question to Ask Different.
I think your question was closed because it was really hard to follow what was being asked, since the formatting and grammar wasn't the best. I've cleaned up your question to make it more clear what was being asked, and reopened it.

The problem I, and I believe the other close-voters, had with the question, is that it asks how to recover (save) data from a reset iPad, which has inherently nothing to do with whatever game happens to be affected by it.
Additionally, it asks how to recover that data for multiple games, which are likely stored in different formats in different paths (not that that would matter if all data was actually fully deleted).
I suggest asking this question on AskDifferent, which is dedicated to Apple products. Good luck!
I VTCed your question again would have VTCed your question again (which is how we keep this site focused and clean, and is by no means a bad thing :), but since it was reopened by a moderator and skipped the Review Queues, I currently cannot.

That's a really good point, and I'll take the 2 upvotes on this question to mean 2 other people would've closed this again as well if they could. I've gone ahead and migrated this question over to Ask Different.

Just a note that [su] doesn't accept questions about mobile/tablet usage, unless it's interfacing with a PC. Also, [so] is about programming, and end-user usage is off-topic.

@antimo Thanks, I wasn't sure - updated!
